# varchar storage and comparisons in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, varchar

I have a large table with a structure similar to this:

```
Id       bigint primary key
Sequence int
Parent   int foreign key
Data1    varchar(20)
Data2    varchar(20)
Data3    varchar(20)
Data4    varchar(20)
Data5    varchar(20)
```

Data 1-5 are text fields (mostly numbers and dashes) and can be used to help prevent accidentally recording duplicates, but the data can actually duplicate occasionally. We have to let the user confirm that yes it's OK it's a duplicate.

This duplicate check can be time consuming with millions of rows. I've been tasked to ensure we can deal with tripling the amount of data we are keeping in this database. I've been told by previous developers that the current process will not work with that much data (there is of course a lot more going on with the data than I'm including here, and though the actual query for finding duplicates is pretty simple this part of the system is apparently sensitive to additional latency). I have not done experiments myself to prove this but I trust their judgement, and regardless I'd like to reduce the impact as much as possible. Unfortunately, I do not have a huge volume to test with until fairly late in the process. So while I have time I would like to try to be set up to test a few scenarios when I get a window of time on the test server.

All 5 fields must match to be counted as a duplicate. I'm skeptical that this could *never* change, but I'm being told that for the foreseeable future all 5 must match exactly. I'm thinking that by adding a indexed column that is a hash of the combined values, I will be able to find potential duplicates much faster. I would still have to compare the individual values to account for hash collisions though. Would I gain anything by combining the values themselves too? So a hash column, and a single column with all 5 values in a delimited string that I use to compare rather than compare each value separately?

It seems like I would only benefit if varchars are not stored with the rest of the row, which I always assumed they were. However that doesn't seem to be the case. I'm having a hard time finding specific information, but it seems that if my row is less than 8060 bytes, the full 20 characters will be allocated in the row. Only if the row is over 8060 will some varchar columns be chose to move into a separate page.

Any documentation that explains how small varchars are stored, and any suggestions regarding whether or not combining the columns into a single column will have a performance impact would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
This table will have millions of rows (say 10 million for an estimate). Each row will definitely have a maximum length of less than 8060 bytes, though I can't give you an exact number right now.

Comment: varchar(20) will be stored with the rest of the row, just like, say, an int would be.  You can control where to store varchar(max) and similar.  See the section "large value types out of row" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library /ms173530%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a persistent calculated field that contains a `CHECKSUM` on the 5 fields, and use that to perform the comparisons.

The `CHECKSUM` field will be unique for that specific combination of fields, and is stored as an `INT` that results in a much easier target for comparisons in a `WHERE` clause.

```
USE tempdb; /* create this in tempdb since it is just a demo */

CREATE TABLE dbo.t1
(
    Id       bigint constraint PK_t1 primary key clustered identity(1,1)
    , Sequence int
    , Parent   int not null constraint df_T1_Parent DEFAULT ((0))
    , Data1    varchar(20)
    , Data2    varchar(20)
    , Data3    varchar(20)
    , Data4    varchar(20)
    , Data5    varchar(20)
    , CK AS CHECKSUM(Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5) PERSISTED
);

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.t1 (Sequence, Parent, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5)
VALUES (1,1,'test','test2','test3','test4','test5');

SELECT *
FROM dbo.t1;
GO
```

[image]

```
/* this row will NOT get inserted since it already exists in dbo.t1 */
INSERT INTO dbo.t1 (Sequence, Parent, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5)
SELECT 2, 3, 'test', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5'
WHERE Checksum('test','test2','test3','test4','test5') NOT IN (SELECT CK FROM t1);

/* still only shows the original row, since the checksum for the row already
exists in dbo.t1 */
SELECT *
FROM dbo.t1;
```

In order to support a large number of rows, you'd want to create an NON-UNIQUE index on the `CK` field.

By the way, you neglected to mention the number of rows you are expecting in this table; that information would be instrumental in making great recommendations.

In-row data is limited to a maximum of 8060 *bytes*, which is the size of a single page of data, less the required overhead for each page.  Any single row larger than that will result in some off-page storage of row data.  I'm certain other contributors to http://dba.stackexchange.com can give you a much more concise definition of the engine internals regarding storage of large rows.  How big is your largest row, presently?

If items in `Data1, Data2, Data3...` have the same values occurring in a different order, the checksum will be different, so you may want to take that into consideration.

Following a brief discussion with the fantastic [Mark Storey-Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2374/mark-storey-smith) on [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17971069#17971069), I'd like to offer a similar, although potentially better choice for calculating a hash on the fields in question.  You could alternately use the `HASHBYTES()` function in the calculated column.  `HASHBYTES()` has some gotchas, such as the necessity to concatenate your fields together, including some type of delimiter between the field values, in order to pass `HASHBYTES()` a single value.  For more information about `HASHBYTES()`, Mark recommended [this](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/TomLannen/bidn-blog/2265/using-hashbytes-to-compare-columns) site.  Clearly, MSDN also has some great info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx

Comment: One of my co-workers is concerned about the extra burden a checksum or hashbyte calculated field would put on the SQL server, and would rather insert this hash pre-calculated on the horizontally scalable service layer. Then we could use an SHA1 generated hash with less collisions than CHECKSUM. What do you think of that?

Comment: Also, I wondered about HASHBYTES. Are indexes on binary fields like that going to be close to as efficient as an integer? The field would have to be much bigger than 4 bytes wouldn't it? I don't really know anything about HASHBYTES and have never indexed binary fields.

Comment: The expense of generating the checksum/hash is in CPU time and even then it isn't very high, so should be insignificant compared to the general cost of writing new/updated rows. Doing it in the data layer means that the database can enforce it always getting updated rather than risking later code touching the table and someone forgetting that this needs to be done.

Comment: @Max Vernon- I read your conversation on the The Heap and I wondered about Mark's comment that you could fore go "Persisted" and just create an index on the calculated column. Can you explain more about that? Is that because the index will save the calculated value so there's no point in updating the row itself? How does it know to update the index if one of the values changes? Just not sure I understood that part.

Comment: @Dean `CAST` the output to `BIGINT`.

Comment: @Mark won't I lose some precision? That would work for a subset of algorithms I guess.

Comment: @Dean and Max: Using `HASHBYTES` would be fine, and while larger (SHA1 = 20 bytes compared to the 4 for an `INT`) you do greatly reduce collision potential. And really, 10 million rows, even 50 million, really isn't much when doing an equality search on a fixed-length, non-string (or string using a `_BIN2` collation) field. An `INT` is a `BINARY(4)`. The result of `HASHBYTES` is `VARBINARY(8000)` but can be converted to `BINARY(20)` (as that is what SHA1 is). You would definitely lose precision if converting to `BIGINT` which is `BINARY(8)`. (continued)

Comment: @Dean and Max: **1)** re: the blog post about HASHBYTES, if on SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can use `CONCAT` which handles the NULL and datatype conversion issues. `SELECT CONCAT(name, N'|', [object_id], N'|', principal_id, N'|', create_date), CONVERT(BINARY(20), HASHBYTES(N'SHA1', CONCAT(name, N'|', [object_id], N'|', principal_id, N'|', create_date))), * FROM sys.objects;` **2)** As an example it's fine, but the `INSERT...SELECT` shown above shouldn't be used in Production as it can prevent valid INSERTs if there are collisions. Maybe that can be noted so people don't just copy and paste?